# Would adding an INDEX on varchar column in Mysql increase performance?

Tags: mysql, index

I have the following table to store log messages:

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `timestamp` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `logger` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `level` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `message` varchar(4000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `thread` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `file` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `line` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `machine` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10321 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

There will be lots of SELECTs with a `WHERE machine = 'xyz'`

Would making this column an INDEX improve performance on that?

Comment: Yes, it would...

Comment: k thx, if that is so easy, then why not make every column an INDEX?

Comment: @oleole That's a different question. But will you also have a lot of Selects with `where column = 'xyz-something'`, for every column of the table?

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ: not all of them, but probably 2 of them. like `WHERE machine='xyz' AND level='ERROR'`

Comment: @oleole then you can create an index over those two columns (combined). In short - indexes make those selects faster but they make all inserts and updates a bit slower and take some memory and disk space, so having index which is not used is just a waste. And with multicolumn indexes the actual possible combinations are too many, so you only create those you need.

Comment: You probably have `WHERE machine = 'xyz' ORDER BY timestamp`?  If so, then this would be even better:  `INDEX(machine, timestamp)`.  And, if you have a `WHERE machine = 'xyz'`, but not that `ORDER BY`, the index is still useful.  [More on indexing](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is yes, indexing **varchar** data field increases the performance but it depends on the query you performed against that particular table. Lets consider the following two entities,

```
Card

Card Id (PK)  
Card Type  
Card Name

Registration

Reg Id (PK)   
Card Id (FK)   
Number of Registration
```

Lets consider a query, **what are the total number of registration by card type?**

Here, the card type is **not frequently updated**, it is either **Credit or Debit Card.** Therefore index on the card type data field is a good choice. Card type contains the values **Credit card and Debit Card** only.

If your non-key data field have such data and you need to perform the query in such a way mentioned above, you can create a non-unique key index for performance.

I hope this answer will help you. Thank you.